# Merge SQL Tables and autofill new records

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have two tables I need to merge together. The merge will take a table of dates, add it into a table with other information and in doing do, create new records. Is there a way to auto-complete the new records with information from the first record. Example:

Table 1:

```
Tag  location  Due Date
1       5
```

Table 2:

```
Date
1/1/17
1/7/17
1/14/17
1/21/17
```

When I merge, I want table 1 to look like:

```
Tag  location  Due Date
1       5       1/1/17
                1/7/17
                1/14/17
                1/21/17
```

and have the tag # and location # autofill so that each new record shows 1 and 5.

Comment: What is the criteria here? Each new record in your desired results doesn't show 1 and 5... just the first one. What logic are you using here/can you explain better? What if there is more records in Table 1. What would it look like? Which record would get which date?

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  Which one is this????  SQL Server or MySQL, can't be both!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cross join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

This will join every row of each table to every row in the other table. In the limited example you posted, you'll get all the different dates, and the tag/location will repeat. If there are two tag/locations, you'll get 8 rows, every date will appear twice and each tag/location pair will appear 4 times etc..

Another example:

```
TableA TableB
A      1
B      2
C      3

A cross join B

A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, this will do the job:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Tag INT,
    Location INT,
    DueDate DATE
    );
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    MyDate DATE
    );
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES
(1, 5, NULL);

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES
('2017-01-01'),
('2017-01-07'),
('2017-01-14'),
('2017-01-21');


INSERT INTO Table1 (Tag, Location, DueDate)
SELECT CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Tag END,
       CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Location END,
       MyDate
FROM
(
    SELECT T1.Tag,
           T1.Location,
           T2.MyDate,
           ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Tag ORDER BY Tag) AS RN
    FROM Table1 T1 CROSS JOIN Table2 T2 
) SQ;

DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE DueDate IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM Table1;
```

Results:

```
+------+----------+---------------------+
| Tag  | Location |       DueDate       |
+------+----------+---------------------+
| 1    | 5        | 01.01.2017 00:00:00 |
| NULL | NULL     | 07.01.2017 00:00:00 |
| NULL | NULL     | 14.01.2017 00:00:00 |
| NULL | NULL     | 21.01.2017 00:00:00 |
+------+----------+---------------------+
```

If you want to fill `Tag` and `Location` columns, use:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Tag, Location, DueDate)
SELECT T1.Tag,
       T1.Location,
       T2.MyDate
FROM Table1 T1 CROSS JOIN Table2 T2;

DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE DueDate IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: From the explanation above, it seems that he does not want NULL values in Tag and Location, but wants those to be autofilled with 1 and 5, respectively.

Comment: @KindaTechy I though _I want table 1 to look like_ is the expected results. Update the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this. This is working fine in mysql Server and MS SQL SERVER

```
select k.Tag,k.Location,u.Mydate Mydate
from
(
    SELECT T1.Tag,
            T1.Location,
            MIN(T2.MyDate) MyDate
    FROM Table1 T1 CROSS JOIN Table2 T2 
    GROUP BY T1.Tag,
            T1.Location
)k 
RIGHT JOIN 
(
    SELECT T1.Tag,
            T1.Location,
            T2.MyDate
    FROM Table1 T1 CROSS JOIN Table2 T2     
)u ON k.Tag = u.Tag AND k.Location = u.Location
AND k.MyDate = u.Mydate


/*------------------------
OUTPUT
------------------------*/
Tag         Location    Mydate
----------- ----------- ----------
1           5           2017-01-01
NULL        NULL        2017-01-07
NULL        NULL        2017-01-14
NULL        NULL        2017-01-21

(4 row(s) affected)
```